# Android P - GenerateKeyPair

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

While targeting my app to Android 9 Preview I get an error when trying to generate a **KeyPair**. I'm using the following code:

```
public void createKeysM(String alias, boolean requireAuth) {

    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        alias,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, F4))
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(requireAuth)
                        .build());
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Log.d(TAG, "Public Key is: " + keyPair.getPublic().toString());

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error in the line **KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();**

I'm putting the stack trace at the end of the question. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thank you for your help!

```
04-17 14:15:41.653 com.stackoverflow.mask E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.stackoverflow.mask, PID: 8644
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.stackoverflow.mask.view.DummyBeaconApplication: java.security.ProviderException: Failed to load generated key pair from keystore
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5879)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: Failed to load generated key pair from keystore
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.loadKeystoreKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:530)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:478)
        at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:727)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.domain.shared.KeyManagerImpl.createKeysM(KeyManagerImpl.java:109)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.domain.shared.KeyManagerImpl.createKeys(KeyManagerImpl.java:53)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.domain.shared.DataManager.<init>(DataManager.java:41)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.AppModule.provideDataManager(AppModule.java:78)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.AppModule_ProvideDataManagerFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideDataManagerFactory.java:40)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.AppModule_ProvideDataManagerFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideDataManagerFactory.java:13)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.interactors.UseCaseModuleBeacon_ProvideGetBeaconUseCaseFactory.get(UseCaseModuleBeacon_ProvideGetBeaconUseCaseFactory.java:37)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.interactors.UseCaseModuleBeacon_ProvideGetBeaconUseCaseFactory.get(UseCaseModuleBeacon_ProvideGetBeaconUseCaseFactory.java:12)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.BaseActivityModule_ProvideBeaconPresenterFactory.get(BaseActivityModule_ProvideBeaconPresenterFactory.java:37)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.BaseActivityModule_ProvideBeaconPresenterFactory.get(BaseActivityModule_ProvideBeaconPresenterFactory.java:12)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.AppModule_ProvideBeaconHelperFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideBeaconHelperFactory.java:50)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.modules.AppModule_ProvideBeaconHelperFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideBeaconHelperFactory.java:14)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.components.DaggerAppComponent.injectDummyApplication(DaggerAppComponent.java:1449)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.dagger.components.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:1440)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.view.DummyApplication.onCreate(DummyApplication.java:54)
        at com.stackoverflow.mask.view.DummyBeaconApplication.onCreate(DummyBeaconApplication.kt:28)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5874)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
     Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain X.509 form of public key
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:239)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyPairFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:278)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreKeyPairFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:289)
04-17 14:15:41.657 com.stackoverflow.mask E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.loadKeystoreKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:521)
            ... 30 more
     Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid key blob
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:823)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStorePublicKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:241)
            ... 33 more
```

Comment: Does your code run on a pre-P device/image? If yes you should post your code in the Google bugtracker, not on SO.

Comment: Thank you. I thought this might be some kind of new behaviour introduced in the new OS version. Will open an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opened a bug in google tracker. You can track it here:

[[Developer Preview Android P] Unable to generate java.security.KeyPair](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78206414)